# Multiple Columns into one Column in excel

Tags: excel

I have 5 columns in my excel sheet which are : `HopColourGreen`,`HopColourGreenYellow`,`HopColourGreenBlack`,`HopColourYellowBlack`,`HopColourBlack` their values are `true` or `false` and i want to create a single column called `colour`which will contain for example `Green` if `HopColourGreen` is set to `true`.

Comment: Is only one option set to `TRUE` at any one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a combination of `SUBSTITUTE`, `MATCH`, and `INDEX` you can put the following in `F` and drag down.

`=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:E, 1, MATCH(TRUE, A2:E2, 0)), "HopColour", "")`

```
HopColourGreen  HopColourGreenYellow    HopColourGreenBlack HopColourYellowBlack    HopColourBlack  
TRUE            FALSE                   FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE           =SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:E, 1, MATCH(TRUE, A2:E2, 0)), "HopColour", "")
FALSE           TRUE                    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE           GreenYellow
FALSE           FALSE                   TRUE                FALSE                   FALSE           GreenBlack
FALSE           FALSE                   FALSE               TRUE                    FALSE           YellowBlack
```

You might need to change the `MATCH(TRUE)` to `MATCH("TRUE")` if they're text.

**EDIT**

There is no `MATCH` in french excel, you have to use `EQUIV` instead.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:E; 1; EQUIV(TRUE; A2:E2; 0)); "HopColour"; "")
```

**EDIT 2**

And `SUBSTITUTE` is `SUBSTITUE` in french.

```
=SUBSTITUE(INDEX(A:E; 1; EQUIV(TRUE; A2:E2; 0)); "HopColour"; "")
```

Comment: Excel didn't execute the combination, the error is `nous avons rencontré une erreur dans cette formule` which means "We encountered an error in this formula"

Comment: Did you try with `TRUE` and `"TRUE"`? Also if you're using the french version you might have to modify the formula to use your separator, as it might not be a comma but `;`.

Comment: I tried this  `=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A:E; 1; MATCH("TRUE";A2:E2;0)); "HopColour"; "")` the result was `#NOM?`

Comment: Did you try `TRUE` instead of `"TRUE"`?

Comment: As in without the quotation marks. And did you put this is cell `F2`?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your table to see exactly how it looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142273/discussion-between-tim-wilkinson-and-geoinfo).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=IF(A2=TRUE;"Green";IF(B2=TRUE;"GreenYellow";IF(C2=TRUE;"GreenBlack";IF(D2=TRUE;"YellowBlack";IF(E2=TRUE;"Black")))))
```

Comment: It didn't work, the result was : `#NOM?` (i use the french version of excel)

Comment: Here's the alternative in french of the expression you wrote : `=SI(A2="TRUE";"Green";SI(B2="TRUE";"GreenYellow";SI(C2="TRUE";"GreenBlack";SI(D2="TRUE";"YellowBlack";SI(E2="TRUE";"Black")))))`